# Get the number from the element's id

Tags: javascript

I have some inputs as below:

```
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-1" name="id[]" />
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-2" name="id[]" />
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-3" name="id[]" />
<input type="hidden" id="selected_id-5" name="id[]" />
```

The list can contain more than just 4 elements.

So, I would like to extract the highest number (in our case = 5) from the ids of elements named "id".

Pure JavaScript needed.

**EDIT:** Thank you everybody who answered my question.

Comment: In jQuery it would be `$('input').length`.

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you looking for the highest number, or the last element's number? So if it were ordered, "1, 3, 2", would you want "2" (because it's last) or "3" (because it's highest)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your elements might not be ordered by id, you'll have to check them all to find the highest one.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var highest = 0;
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].name == 'id[]') {
        var current = inputs[i].id.split('-')[1];
        highest = (current > highest) ? current : highest;
    }
}
// Now highest contains the highest numeric id
console.log(highest);
```

Comment: Simple answer *and* it handles multi-digit numbers.

Comment: BUT it assumes you know what the element is!

Comment: @epascarello Well, `document.getElementById`was just an example, and a wrong one (I forgot `.id`!), but it assumues you already have the id on some string. Will edit.

Comment: This kind of defeats the purpose. If he knew the number ahead of time, he could have answered it with just `return 1;`

Comment: @Pete Again, `getElementById` was just an example, I was assuming the id was already stored somewhere else. The question was not clear enough before the edits. Now I have a new answer.

Comment: Just to clarify once again: the original question sounded like "how to get the numeric part from strings like this", now it's more specific.

Comment: Nitpick: This solution is inefficient in a couple of ways. It selects all the inputs and has to check what they are. There are quicker ways to limit and not have to loop. 

It uses a ternary operator and keeps setting the same value if it is the max. 

It also is not comparing numbers with the greater than, but strings.

Comment: @epascarello You're right, it's not the most efficient solution. My purpose was purely instructional, and from my point of view the core issue was not how to select the correct elements, but how to extract the numeric part of their ids, and (after the question got edited) find the highest number among them. Honestly, I now believe both you and I have put more effort into this than the question deserved.

Answer (score 6):

```
var number = element.id.replace(/^[^\d]+/, "");
```

or

```
var number = element.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

**EDIT**: Just saw that you wanted to get the last element:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("id[]");
var element = elements[elements.length - 1];
```

Now you can use either of the methods I have shown above the edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either regex or `slice()`:

```
var num = this.id.match(/(\d+)/)[0];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Mfef8/).

Or, with slice:

```
var num = this.id.slice(-1);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Mfef8/1/).

The option with `slice()`, though, will work only with a single-digit number.

Comment: David, doesn't the `match` return an array? Shouldn't you be accessing a subscript of the array?

Comment: @VivinPaliath: yep! I caught that after a few moments (and since edited to correct!) =)

Answer (score 2):

This assumes that the elements are in numerical order.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName("id[]");
//or var elems = document.getElementById("formId").elements["id[]"];
//or var elems = document.formName.elements["id[]"];
//or var elems = document.forms[0].elements["id[]"];//0 is the index of the form on the page
var lastElem = elems[elems.length-1];
var lastId = lastElem.id;
var parts = lastId.split("-");
var num = parts[1];
alert(num);
```

If they are not in numerical order you would need to loop through and keep track.

```
function getNumber(elem){
    return parseInt(elem.id.split("-")[1],10);
}

var elems = document.getElementsByName("id[]");
var max = getNumber(elems[0]);
for (var i=1;i<elems.length;i++) {
    var num = getNumber(elems[i]);
    if (num>max) {
        max = num;
    }
}
alert(max);
```

Comment: The elements aren't in numerical order!

Comment: Helps if you stick that in your question. You said last, not greatest number.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to do this with something like jQuery because it will handle all the hard parts for you. But if you're using a modern browser, you can do it like this:

```
var highestNum = (function() {
    var highest = 0, r = /\-(\d+)$/, i, elems = document.getElementsByName("id[]");
    for(i=0; i<elems.length; i++) {
        highest = Math.max(highest, +elems[i].id.match(r)[1]);
    }

    return highest;
});
```

This accounts for the elements being potentially out of order, too. <strike>Though it relies on a pretty new browser to work (IE>=8 or anything that's not IE). If you want fallback support to things like IE6, your best bet is to use jQuery or another such library.</strike> With jQuery, the solution would be something like this:

```
var highestNum = (function() {
    var highest = 0, r = /\-(\d+)$/;

    $("input[name='id[]']").each(function() {
         highest = Math.max(highest, +this.id.match(r)[1]);
    });

    return highest;
});
```

**UPDATE:** I cheated a bit off someone else's solution and made it more IE6-friendly. The jQuery solution is still a bit simpler, but the vanilla solution should suit your needs.

Comment: The first example not work in older browsers because of "querySelectorAll"? Or is there something else?

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR Yeah, but after cheating off of @epascarello's solution, I was able to eliminate the need for `document.querySelectorAll()` so it's much more old-IE-friendly. So I think it's the solution he's looking for now.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form is the first one on the page, you can do something like this:

```
var c = document.forms[0].children;

for( var i=0; i<c.length; i++ ) {
    var prefix = "selected_id-";
    if( c[i].id.search( prefix )===0 )
        console.log( c[i].id.substring( prefix.length ) );
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

```
function check(){
 var form = document.forms[0];
 var txtS =  form["id[]"];
 var len = txtS.length;
var numb =txts[len-1].split('-')[1]
}
```

or you can use

```
var elementgroup = document.getElementsByName("id[]");
var nub= elementgroup[elementgroup .length - 1].split('-')[1];
```