# How can I tell jQuery to recognize the ids inside the table?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I had a table in which the buttons click did not work based on the `jQuery` function I defined inside document.ready. Thanks to `Stackoverflow`, I tried the following code and the buttons now work on click (showing their id):

```
        $('.myspecialtable').on('click',"button.btn", function(){
            console.log(this.id);
        });
```

Inside that table, there also `div`s and `span`s which have different `id`s. Unfortunately, they're not recognized by `jQuery`. For example, I want to change the text inside a `span` with `id="aggregated-score"`. Again using `Stackoverflow` previous answered questions, I try the following and nothing happens:

```
        $('.myspecialtable').on('click',"button.btn", function(){
            console.log(this.id);
            $('#aggregated-score span').text('changed!');
        });
```

Even when I try:

```
            var x = $('#aggregated-score span').text('changed!');
            console.log(x)
```

nothing comes up in the console which made me think it is not acting anything on the `id`. What am I doing wrong? How can I tell `jQuery` to recognize the ids inside the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#aggregated-score span` selects an element with the tag `span` that is an descendant of an element that has `aggregated-score` as `id` so so for this code:

```
<span id="aggregated-score"><span></span></span>
```

`#aggregated-score span` would select the inner `span`.

To select a `span` with the `aggregated-score` as `id` you have to use `span#aggregated-score` or just `#aggregated-score` as an `id` has to be unique anyways.

Comment: Can you help me with another thing please. These spans that I have, they have different numbered ids. For example one is aggregated-score-1 and the other is aggregated-score-2. And there is a lot of them. How can I tell jQuery for example when some button with id button-1 is clicked, then change the text of the span with id aggregated-score-1?

Comment: In other words can we use string concatenation inside $()?

Comment: @Mike StackOverflow is an Q&A platform and therefore strictly structured. The comment sections is only to ask for clarification about the answer (or question). And in the question section you should only ask one question, and create a new question with a [mcve] for the new topic. Besides that you should do some research yourself before asking a question.

Comment: I am learning. I did a lot of research for both my questions but found nothing useful even in the documentations. Its really annoying when people say that. Anyway that does not mean I am not thankful for you answering my first question. Sometimes all a learner needs is such quick hints which only experienced developers can provide, not documentations.

Comment: @Mike The research also includes looking at how the platform you are using works. And to show that you have tried something and to explain where exactly you have a problem with, such basic questions a most certainly already fully or partially answered by similar questions like [Using jQuery, how do you select another element based on the clicked element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423851), or a combination of multible [Get the number from the element's id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307840), so get the number from `button-1` and append it to `aggregated-score-`.

Comment: Again, finding that link is something you as an experienced developer can do. Sometimes, I as a beginner simply am not familiar with that sufficient set of keywords which can lead me to the best answer to my question.

Comment: @Mike sure but still, the least what you can do is to check how the platform works (not asking new questions in comments). And provide an [mcve] of what you have tried in the new question so that it can be seen that you at least tried something yourself. And writing the idea what you want to do, e.g. `How do extract the number out of "button-1" and use it to find "aggregated-score-1"` I mean that's basically what you want to do, and if you formulate what you want to do you probably already find your solution yourself, if not you at least have show that you thought about the problem.

Comment: Stackoverflow is about helping each other grow. And you helped me. Thanks

Comment: @Mike you also need it to see it from the perspective of someone answering. As an experienced developer you need to check if other answers in the topic we are good at are incorrect or misleading so that we can comment on those (so that this platform can maintain its high standard), and we also want to give as many answers as possible, and we do all that in our spare time. So the more you take care when you asking questions, the more we can contribute to the platform because we have more time to help.

Comment: I simply do not agree with that. A time spent for helping someone who asks a basic question, is not always a waste of time. Sometimes we're meant to be there at that particular time to answer that particular question.